# Fluid simulation destroys CPU temperature

Tags: fluid-simulation

I didn't realize blender was putting so much strain on my CPU when I bake fluid simulations.
I'm doing 200 Resolution divisions and 4 Mesh 'Up res factors'
The CPU temps reach up to 95c and keeps throttling and going back and fourth from 85-92c.
I also can't use anything else on my pc while the baking is running
I'm using stock cooling so it's pretty bad, But I just want to limit blender to use less cores and/or threads.
Is there any way to make blender utilize less CPU power?

Edit: Decreasing blender's priority doesn't help as it will still run at 100% if no other programs are running. My CPU (I7-10700) Isn't overclocked and its max temperature is 100c. running at 95c for hours is way too dangerous. I'm asking if there's a way to limit its usage or core usage.

Comment: Sadly not, as the program will still run at 100% if no other programs are running. If I was rendering I would've been able to limit threads but, this is a fluid simulation, and there's no option to do so.

Comment: If you work with a calculation-intensive software such as blender, it might be a good idea to optimize your system's cooling. Get a BIG heatspreder and a potent fan and you will be able to keep your temperature down even under sustained heavy load. 

Also, it is a good idea to keep your case clean and remove dust buildup regularly.

Comment: "*I'm asking if there's a way to limit its usage or core usage.*" Have you read any of the other suggestions in the linked post?

Comment: Yes I have, but that puts more stress on less cores which makes the temps go over 95c. So it doesn't help at all. I'm probably gonna go with haarigertroll's suggestions and try to get better cooling